# Datadog tracing using Open Telemetry - ingested spans increased

Tags: go, datadog, open-telemetry

I have trouble understanding the ingested spans mechanism.

We have a go application that uses Datadog SDK to trace.

For example, a service has two spans:

- span A: `serviceName`: my-service, `operationName`: some.operation, `resourceName`: Some Resource
- span B: `serviceName`: my-service, `operationName`: other.operation, `resourceName`: Other Resource

span A is the root span, and the parent of span B,
In Datadog UI, we can only see metrics for `some.operation` (hits, latency, etc...)

After we moved to open telemetry, we suddenly can also see metrics for span B (`other.operation`) (in the span hirarchy, the UI still presents span B as a child of span A.

Also, after moving to trace using OTEL SDK, the ingested spans increased a lot, without explicitly adding new spans in the code.

So I don't understand the ingested spans mechanism, before tracing with the OTEL SDK, only root spans for a service were considered ingested? Even though we still see the child span in the flame graph?

And what causes span B to suddenly be considered as ingested after moving to OTEL?

Comment: I think the otel SDK defaults to head sampling, where the decision to sample a span or not is done once at the beginning of the trace regardless of configured sample rates in the middle. But should be able to configure the collector to reduce that? Does this help?: https://docs.datadoghq.com/opentelemetry/guide/ingestion_sampling_with_opentelemetry/#reducing-your-ingestion-volume

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yeah, the more I'm trying to read it, the more confused I get... :) You're right, the default is "ParentBased(AlwaysSample())". Does that mean that I get all of the spans ingested and calculated? What I don't understand is the term ingested spans. When tracing with Datadog SDK, I see spans in the UI but they aren't considered ingested?

Comment: Probably worth a call with your DD account or support team, tbh. 